# How to remove empty/blank lines from a file in Unix (including spaces)?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, text, parsing

How do I remove empty/blank (including spaces only) lines in a file in Unix/Linux using the command line?

contents of file.txt

```
Line:Text
1:<blank>
2:AAA
3:<blank>
4:BBB
5:<blank>
6:<space><space><space>CCC
7:<space><space>
8:DDD
```

output desired

```
1:AAA
2:BBB
3:<space><space><space>CCC
4:DDD
```

Comment: For awk, see: [Remove blank lines in awk](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128328/21471), or [using grep](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1611809/55075), in general, see: [How to remove blank lines from a file in shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101440/21471)

Comment: [same question and same answer given over here but with much more votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414489/52074)

Comment: This is an epic answer that pretty much gives every possible solution using grep, sed, awk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed/39139322#39139322

Answer (score 198):

This sed line should do the trick:

```sh
sed -i '/^$/d' file.txt
```

The `-i` means it will edit the file in-place.

Comment: It actually needs to be "/^ *$/d" to remove lines that only contain spaces.

Comment: @SeanReifschneider That requirement was not in the question when this answer was written?

Comment: @SeanReifschneider Would "/^\s*$/d" not be better as it would include tabs? Whilst it's not mentioned in the original post, it seems a stronger option to me.

Comment: [adding the `\s*` is the same solution given by stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414489/52074)

Comment: I get `bad flag in substitute command: 'e'`

Comment: This command is not compatible with macOS/BSD, secondly it does not produce the same output as OP requested (it produces 5 lines, not 4).

Answer (score 118):

#### `grep`

Simple solution is by using [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/grep) ([GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) or [BSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep)) command as below.

- Remove blank lines (not including lines with spaces).

  ```
  grep . file.txt
  ```
- Remove completely blank lines (including lines with spaces).

  ```
  grep "\S" file.txt
  ```

Note: If you get unwanted colors, that means your `grep` is aliases to `grep --color=auto` (check by `type grep`). In that case, you can add `--color=none` parameter, or just run the command as `\grep` (which ignores the alias).

---

#### `ripgrep`

Similar with [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) (suitable for much larger files).

Remove blank lines not including lines with spaces:

```
rg -N . file.txt
```

or including lines with spaces:

```
rg -N "\S" file.txt
```

---

See also:

- [How to remove blank lines from a file (including tab and spaces)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101440/21471)
- With `sed`: [Delete empty lines using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16414410/55075)
- With `awk`: [Remove blank lines using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128328/21471)

Comment: `grep .` seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: The downside of `grep .` compared to the other solutions is that it will highlight all the text in red. The other solutions can preserve the original colors. Compare `unbuffer apt search foo | grep .` to `unbuffer apt search foo | grep -v ^$`

Comment: @wisbucky You see colors, because `grep` is aliased to `grep --color=auto` on your system (check by: `type grep`). You can run it as `\grep` or use `--color=none` parameter.

Comment: @kenorb If you use `grep --color=none .`, you will get all white text, which overrides the color formatting of the original command (example: `apt search foo`)

Comment: `grep .` will match lines containing only spaces, which the OP says is not desired.

Comment: @JimL. A dot (`.`) in `grep` matches any character, so it'll print all non-empty lines. Even the lines with a single empty space are going to be printed.

Comment: Yes, and the OP wishes lines containing only spaces to be removed.

Comment: @JimL. I've improved answer with the solution removing lines with spaces.

Comment: Actually, I think none of the other answers providing what OP requested (exempt [Steven one](https://serverfault.com/a/915814/130437)).

Answer (score 37):

```
sed '/^$/d' file.txt
```

d is the sed command to delete a line. `^$` is a regular expression matching only a blank line, a line start followed by a line end.

Comment: This command does not produce the same output as OP requested (it produces 5 lines, not 4).

Comment: You likely need `sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' file.txt`. Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414489/123897

Answer (score 23):

You can use the -v option with grep to remove the matching empty lines.

Like this

```
grep -Ev "^$" file.txt
```

Comment: I don't believe you need the `-E`, at least not with GNU grep, but apart from that I'm so pleased to see this done with grep!  It's what I reach for in preference to sed, every time; in-line filters seem to me to be better than in-line editors.

Comment: If you want to skip the commented and blank lines, especially while dealing with conf files use `grep -Ev '^#|^$' file.txt`

Comment: `grep (GNU grep) 3.4` requires -E if you are using @GovindKailas' command

Answer (score 20):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk NF file.txt
```

With Awk, `NF` only set on non-blank lines. When this condition match, Awk default action is to print the whole line.

Answer (score 9):

To remove empty lines, you could squeeze new line repeats with `tr`:

```
cat file.txt | tr -s '\n' '\n'
```

Comment: This produces 6 lines, not 4 as OP requested.

Comment: the second `'\n'` seems to be unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

xargs if you dont mind stripping leading whitespace

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm alpine sh
/ # cat <<eof > /tmp/file
> one
>
>   two
> three
>
>
>   four
> eof
/ # cat /tmp/file
one

  two
three


  four
/ # cat /tmp/file | xargs -n1
one
two
three
four
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Ex/Vim

Here is the method using [`ex` editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) (part of Vim):

```
ex -s +'v/\S/d' -cwq test.txt
```

For multiple files (edit in-place):

```
ex -s +'bufdo!v/\S/d' -cxa *.txt
```

<sup>Note: The `:bufdo` command is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).</sup>

Without modifying the file (just print on the standard output):

```
cat test.txt | ex -s +'v/\S/d' +%p +q! /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

For me @martigin-heemels command was throwing error this fixed it (ie a dummy param to i),

`sed -i '' '/^$/d' file.txt`